# xpaths and html parsing using mechanize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parsing, mechanize

Im using mechanize to parse `http://www.hammacher.com/Category/Default.aspx?uq=Gifts-Under-30&all=True`

What xpath can I use to get to each href on that page so that each product page can be passed?

This is what i am trying now, and not getting a full url:

```
page = agent.get('http://www.hammacher.com/Category/Default.aspx?uq=Gifts-Under-30&all=True')    
page.parser.xpath('//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "product_list_sub", " " ))]//a')[5].attributes['href'].to_s
```

Also, is it possible, when using Mechanize to parse for two different xpath selectors in the same statement?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
page.links_with(:href => /Product\/Default.aspx\?sku/)
```